# JSONPath - Is there any way to get the parent node of JSONPath?

Tags: php, jsonpath

For a JSONPath expression `$.event.data.name`, I need to get `$.event`. Is there any way to get this in PHP other than using regular expressions?

Comment: Is there any package avaialble?